# A question about transformations in probability.

Tags: probability

I'm solving some old question papers and this problem is really irritating me. Please help me with this problem.

A random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. $X$ is transformed to a new random variable $Y = T(X) = a \tan (X)$, where $a>0$. Find the probability density function of $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}$, $-\frac \pi 2< x < \frac \pi 2$ be the probability density function for $X$ and note that $\tan X$ is a monotonically increasing function of $X$, so we can find the density of $Y$, call it $f_Y(y)$ via a Jacobian transformation $$f_Y(y) = f_X(x(y)) \left| \frac{dx}{dy} \right|$$ writing $x$ as a function of $Y$ we have $$x(y) = \tan^{-1} (y/a)$$ so $$\left| \frac{dx}{dy} \right| =\left| \frac{1}{a+y^2/a} \right| = \frac{1}{a(1+(y/a)^2)}$$ Finally note that $-\frac \pi 2\leq x \leq \frac \pi 2$ so $$-\frac \pi 2< \tan^{-1} (y/a) < \frac \pi 2$$ and thus $$-\infty <y< \infty$$ Therefore $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\pi a(1+(\frac ya)^2)}, \qquad -\infty <y< \infty$$ This is  known as a Cauchy distribution.